# Show that the equation of the normal line with the minimum y-coordinate is $ y = \frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}x + {1\over k}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, conic-sections, area

> > Question: The curve in the figure is the parabola $y=kx^2$ where $k>0$.
> >
> > Several normal lines to this parabola are also shown. Consider the points in the first quadrant from which the normal lines are drawn. Notice that as the $x$ coordinate gets smaller, the $y$-coordinate of the intersection of the normal with the other arm of the parabola also decreases until it reaches a minimum, and then it increases. The normal line with the minimum $y$ coordinate is dotted.
> >
> > $(a)$ Show that the equation of the normal to the parabola at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is $y = {-x\over 2kx_0} + kx_0^2 + {1\over 2k}$
> >
> > (b) Show that the equation of the normal line with the minimum y-coordinate is $ y =  \frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}x + {1\over k} $
> >
> > [image]

---

What I have done:

> > $(a)$ Show that the equation of the normal to the parabola at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is $y = {-x\over 2kx_0} + kx_0^2 + {1\over 2k}$

$$ f(x) = kx^2 $$

$$ f( x_{0}) = kx_{0}^2 $$

$$ f'(x) = 2kx $$

$$ f'(x_{0}) = 2kx_0 $$

$$ Normal = -1/m $$

$$ m= {-1\over 2kx_0} $$

$$ y-y_1 = m (x-x_1) $$

$$ y-kx_0^2 = {-1\over 2kx_0}(x-x_0) $$

$$ y = {-x\over 2kx_0} + kx_0^2 + {1\over 2k} $$

> > (b) Show that the equation of the normal line with the minimum y-coordinate is $ y =  \frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}x + {1\over k} $

$$ y =  \frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}x + {1\over k} $$

$$ {-1\over m} = \frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2} $$

$$ m = \sqrt{2} $$

$$ f'(x) = 2kx $$

$$ 2kx = \sqrt{2} $$

$$ x = {\sqrt{2}\over 2k} $$

$$ f({\sqrt{2}\over 2k}) =  {1\over 2k}$$

$$ y-y_1 = m (x-x_1) $$

$$ y - {1\over 2k} = \frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2} (x-{\sqrt{2}\over 2k}) $$

$$ y =  \frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}x + {1\over k} $$

However I am stuck trying to prove that this is the minimum y coordinate.

I've attempted

$$ y = y$$

$$ kx^2 = {-x\over 2kx_0} + kx_0^2 + {1\over 2k}$$

$$ kx^2 + (\frac{1}{2kx_0})x -(kx_0^2 + \frac{1}{2k}) = 0$$

$$ x={-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}$$

$$ x={- (\frac{1}{2kx_0})\pm\sqrt{ (\frac{1}{4k^2x_0^2})-4(k)(-kx_0^2 - \frac{1}{2k})} \over 2k}$$

$$ x={- (\frac{1}{2kx_0})\pm\sqrt{ \frac{1}{4k^2x_0^2}-4(-k^2x_0^2 - \frac{k}{2k})} \over 2k}$$

$$ x={-\frac{1}{2kx_0}\pm\sqrt{ \frac{1}{4k^2x_0^2}+4k^2x_0^2 + 2} \over 2k}$$

$$ x={-\frac{1}{2kx_0}\pm\sqrt{ (2kx_0 + \frac{1}{2kx_0})^2} \over 2k}$$

$$ x={-\frac{1}{2kx_0}\pm { (2kx_0 + \frac{1}{2kx_0})} \over 2k}$$

$$ x = x_0 $$

$$ x = \frac{-1}{2k^2x_0} - x_0 $$

Now I am lost..

Comment: Where is this problem from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did almost all the work. From
$$ x={-\frac{1}{2kx_0}\pm { (2kx_0 + \frac{1}{2kx_0})} \over 2k}$$

the $x$ you are looking for is the one with the '$-$':
$$x={-\frac{1}{2kx_0}- { (2kx_0 + \frac{1}{2kx_0})} \over 2k}=-\frac{1}{2k^2x_0}-x_0$$
(the other one is simply $x=x_0$).
Now 
$$y=k\left(-\frac{1}{2k^2x_0}-x_0\right)^2$$
so you just have to minimize 
$$\frac{1}{2k^2x_0}+x_0$$
and it's easy to see that the minimum is at $x_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt2k}$.

Comment: Thank you, I have a question , why do we take the negative one?

Comment: @dydxx Taking the positive value gives you $x = x_0$, which is where the normal line and tangent line intersect.  You want to find the other point where the normal line intersects the parabola.

Comment: thanks, also i found the minimum x_0 how do I know that will give me the minimum y_0?

Comment: @dydxx because $y$ is just $k$ multiplied by the square of an expression containing $x_0$, so to minimize $y$, you just minimize that expression.

Comment: $y = \frac{2}{k}$ right? after subbing in x_0 and simplifying?

Comment: Yes it is right.